# How to debounce Lodash call to fetch in Typescript properly?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, lodash

I'm relatively new to React & Typescript/JS and am trying to understand how to debounce a call to a promise properly.  There's a button to increment/decrement a desired purchase quantity and only after a certain period of time do I want to actually execute the call to the backend API, to avoid the user just repeatedly hitting the +/- buttons and spamming the server.

```
import debounce from 'lodash/debounce'

const [isQueryingPrice, setIsQueryingPrice] = useState(false);
const [desiredPurchaseQty, setDesiredPurchaseQty] = useState<number>(1);

const changeQty = (delta: number) => {
    setDesiredPurchaseQty(desiredPurchaseQty + delta);
    setIsQueryingPrice(true);
    debounce(fetchPrice, 1000)();

}
const incrementQty = (event: any) => {
    changeQty(1);
}
const decrementQty = (event: any) => {
    changeQty(-1);
}

const fetchPrice = (qty: number) => {
    // not sure that arrow function wrapping fetch is the best approach here?
    // some imaginary api
    fetch("https://api.example.com/get-price?qty=" + qty).then((response) => {
        return response.json();
    });

}

// in my component:
< div>
    <Button onClick={decrementQty}>Dec</Button>
    <Button onClick={incrementQty}>Inc</Button>
</div>
```

However, whilst the increment/decrement works, the debounced function is fired multiple times when the timer expires.  I want to have a single promise executed when the user has stopped pressing the change quantity buttons, and I want the promise execution to respect the count, i.e. if the user presses the count button 3 times, such that the total is 4, then the call to get the price should be for a quantity of 4.

I think this might be that the calls to change state cause a re-render and a creation of a new debounced function and I think perhaps the calls to the debounce function don't cause the old scheduled callbacks to be cleared.  However, this is where my knowledge of JS starts to break down...

I'd also like to know how the approach should work for an initial load of price: I think there's a call inside a `useEffect()` to get the price when the page first loads.

Comment: Can you make a reproducible example in a sandbox? [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/vanilla-react-template-irhcq). It's unclear what behavior you expect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't want to create a new debounced function every time you change quantity and certainly not on every render.

Here I've wrapped the original `fetchPrice` with the debounce function and also saved state so we can use the same debounced function across renders.

`const [debouncedFetchPrice] = useState(() => debounce(fetchPrice, 1000));`

and then in `changeQty` function you should call `debouncedFetchPrice` instead of `fetchPrice`

This should mean it will trigger with the latest `desiredPurchaseQty` value after a 1000 millis delay.

Furthermore...

I've found this article useful in the past to create a `useDebounce` hook with useEffect. Check it out
https://dev.to/gabe_ragland/debouncing-with-react-hooks-jci

Comment: I'm finding that this fixes the issue of repeated queries for multiple button pushes, but the query that is executed does not seem to use the updated state, it uses the state from the first query only (i.e. the changes in `changeQty()` are not respected). Any ideas please?

Comment: Did you call the `debouncedFetchPrice(desiredPurchaseQty)`. Please make an example with [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/vanilla-react-template-irhcq)... even if you have to mock the api call with a timeout or something.

Comment: i was able to understood with your explanation, after a lot of research how to make a debounce. Thank you.